# LaTeX: Trying to add pdf: "TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=20000]."

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I'm new to LaTeX. I was trying to insert a PDF in my LaTeX document with the following command:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[margin=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{gb4e}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\includepdf{myfile1.pdf}
```

However, LaTeX says that my TeX capacity is exceeded:

```
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=20000].

\gb@ifnextchar #1#2#3->
                       \let \reserved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {#2}\def \reserv...
l.61   \catcode`\noexpand\^^A
                             \the\catcode`\^^A\relax}
If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.
```

I tried to expand my TeX capacity but I am not sure that it is the actual problem (and also I did not manage to expand the capacity).

How do I find out if it is actually a capacity issue or something else?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Non-programming questions about LaTeX are best suited for [LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` are missing.

Comment: Do you really need the `gb4e` package? If yes, load it after pdfpages